# Gutenberg/WordPress - Open sidebar by default

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to open the sidebar by default in WordPress Gutenberg interface.

[image]

I wrote this code :

```
const isSidebarOpened = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isEditorSidebarOpened();

    if ( !isSidebarOpened ) {
        wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).openGeneralSidebar();
    }
```

The condition work, but the function `openGeneralSidebar()` don't open the sidebar. Can I have some help please ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

If someone want to do this one day here's the code who work for me :

```
const isSidebarOpened = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isEditorSidebarOpened();

if ( !isSidebarOpened ) {
   wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).openGeneralSidebar();
}
```

Comment: `openGeneralSidebar()` allows a parameter to open a specific plugin's sidebar e.g. `openGeneralSidebar( "edit-post/block" );` to open the current block's sidebar.